# How to navigate to erlang function in emacs by name?

Tags: emacs, erlang

I use emacs-mode. How can I navigate to function definition by name? Emacs has "imenu-add-to-menubar" command but it's not convenient way because I have to select function name from menu.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use <kbd>M-x imenu</kbd> directly—it works only within the current file, though. I bind it to <kbd>Super-i</kbd> in my `.emacs` with:

```
(global-set-key [(super ?i)] 'imenu)
```

Answer (score 4):

Distel package has erl-find-source-under-point function, that is bound to M-. key
You can read more about work with Erlang from Emacs in [my article](http://xtalk.msk.su/~ott/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsErlang.html)

Answer (score 1):

Erlang is one of the many languages supported by [tags](http://www3.erlang.org/doc/man/tags.html).  The Erlang docs [show](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/tools/erlang_mode_chapter.htmlhttp://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/tools/erlang_mode_chapter.html) that you just build the tags file with:

```
find . -name "*.[he]rl" -print | etags -
```

Once you have a TAGS file, you just use <kbd>M-.</kbd>, which calls ['`find-tag`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Tag.html).  This enables jumping to a function name from *anywhere*.